# Jetty: lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ExecutionStrategy.execute()V

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

I upgraded dropwizard to the latest 1.2.4 from 1.0.2. Now I am seeing the below exception in my logs

```
WARN [2018-02-28 11:34:50] o.e.j.u.t.QueuedThreadPool:[?:?:?] - [dw-99] -
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ExecutionStrategy.execute()V
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.run(ManagedSelector.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

`mvn dependency:tree` output is below

```
com.van:restapilayer:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT
+- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jackson:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-util:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.9.4:compile
+- io.dropwizard.modules:dropwizard-elasticsearch:jar:1.2.0-1:compile
|  \- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:2.4.6:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:5.5.4:compile
|     |  \- com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.5:compile
|     +- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.0:compile
|     +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
|     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.8.1:compile
|     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.8.1:compile
|     +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.6.Final:compile
|     +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.2:compile
|     +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.0:compile
|     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.6:compile
|     \- com.twitter:jsr166e:jar:1.1.0:compile
+- com.van:logback-utils:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
|  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
|  +- com.van:common:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  |  +- com.koloboke:koloboke-api-jdk8:jar:1.0.0:compile
|  |  +- com.koloboke:koloboke-impl-jdk8:jar:1.0.0:runtime
|  |  |  \- com.koloboke:koloboke-impl-common-jdk8:jar:1.0.0:runtime
|  |  +- it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:jar:8.1.0:compile
|  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pinpoint:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-xray:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opsworkscm:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-support:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpledb:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-servicecatalog:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-servermigration:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-simpleworkflow:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-storagegateway:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-route53:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-importexport:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-redshift:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-glacier:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iam:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-datapipeline:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancing:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticloadbalancingv2:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticache:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elastictranscoder:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-budgets:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudtrail:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-logs:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-events:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitosync:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directconnect:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudfront:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesis:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-opsworks:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatchmetrics:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codedeploy:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codepipeline:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-config:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lambda:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecs:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ecr:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudhsm:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ssm:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-workspaces:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-machinelearning:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-directory:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-efs:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codecommit:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-devicefarm:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-waf:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-inspector:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-iot:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-api-gateway:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acm:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-gamelift:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dms:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-marketplacemeteringservice:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-discovery:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-applicationautoscaling:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-snowball:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rekognition:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-polly:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-lightsail:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-stepfunctions:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-health:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-codebuild:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-appstream:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-shield:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-batch:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-models:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries:jar:1.11.22:compile
|  |  +- com.van:utility:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  |  +- com.ning:async-http-client:jar:1.9.38:compile
|  |  +- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:3.0.0:compile
|  |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
|  |  +- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:3.0.1:compile
|  |  +- com.librato.metrics:metrics-librato:jar:4.1.2.4:compile
|  |  |  \- com.librato.metrics:librato-java:jar:1.0.13:compile
|  |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:compile
|  |  +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.4:compile
|  |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.4:compile
|  |  |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.4:compile
|  |  |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.4:compile
|  |  +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.4:compile
|  |  |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:compile
|  |  |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.4:compile
|  |  +- com.vmw.vli:licensecheck:jar:1.4-RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
|  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.57:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1:compile
|  |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
|  |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
|  |  |  +- tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.23:compile
|  |  |  +- tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.23:compile
|  |  |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:compile
|  |  |  +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0:compile
|  |  |  |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.6-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.7.1:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core4:jar:4.0.1-incubating:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
|  |  |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  |     +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
|  |  |  |     |  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
|  |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.8:compile
|  |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.8:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.1:compile
|  |  +- org.coursera:metrics-datadog:jar:1.1.13:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.3.6:compile
|  |  |  \- com.datadoghq:java-dogstatsd-client:jar:2.3:compile
|  |  \- com.van:reg-common:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
+- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  \- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
+- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-configuration:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-logging:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-logback:jar:3.2.5:compile
|  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-metrics:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jersey:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.25.1:compile
|  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.25.1:compile
|  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-metainf-services:jar:2.25.1:compile
|  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.25.1:compile
|  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jersey2:jar:3.2.5:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.4:compile
|  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.25.1:compile
|  |  |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.25.1:compile
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-servlets:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  |  \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:jar:3.2.5:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jetty:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jetty9:jar:3.2.5:compile
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-lifecycle:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.2.5:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.2.5:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-servlets:jar:3.2.5:compile
|  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.2.5:compile
|  |  \- com.papertrail:profiler:jar:1.0.2:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.2.5:compile
|  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-request-logging:jar:1.2.4:compile
|  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:1.2.3:compile
|  +- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.7.0:compile
|  \- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid:jetty-setuid-java:jar:1.0.3:compile
+- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.3:compile
|  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
+- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:jar:1.2.4:test
|  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:compile
|  \- org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers:jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory:jar:2.25.1:test
|     \- org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework:jersey-test-framework-core:jar:2.25.1:test
+- org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:jar:1.3.0:compile
|  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
+- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.5.0:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.4.2:compile
|  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.0:compile
|  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
+- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.0:compile
+- org.apache.shiro:shiro-web:jar:1.2.3:compile
+- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
+- com.van:contracts:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:base-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:core-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.9-RC1:compile
|  |  |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
|  |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
|  +- com.van:vshield-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:nsx-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:cisco-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:vcenter-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:force10-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:flow-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:openstack-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:juniper-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  \- com.van:pan-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- com.van:rpc-saasinterface:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- com.van:storage-common:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:data-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  |  \- org.ardverk:patricia-trie:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- net.spy:spymemcached:jar:2.11.4:compile
|  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.2.6:compile
|  +- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:3.7:compile
|  \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.4:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
|  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.2.1.Final:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
+- com.van:kin-storage-metrics:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:1.2.0-cdh5.7.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-annotations:jar:1.2.0-cdh5.7.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:jar:1.2.0-cdh5.7.0:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.0:compile
|  |  |     +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.2:compile
|  |  |     +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.10:compile
|  |  |     \- org.eclipse.jdt:core:jar:3.1.1:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:jar:1.2.0-cdh5.7.0:compile
|  |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5-cdh5.7.0:compile
|  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.2.0-incubating:compile
|  |  +- org.jruby.jcodings:jcodings:jar:1.0.8:compile
|  |  +- org.jruby.joni:joni:jar:2.1.2:compile
|  |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.0:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.7.0:compile
|  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
|  |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
|  |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
|  |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.7.1:compile
|  |  \- com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:compile
|  \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:compile
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile
+- com.van:storage-config:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4.1208.jre7:compile
|  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
|  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
|  +- com.van:dedup:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  \- org.elasticsearch.module:lang-groovy:jar:2.3.1:compile
|     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:indy:2.4.6:compile
+- com.van:programs:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:jar:1.1.3:compile
|  +- com.van:model-utils:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:event-manager:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:storage-flowstore:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:aws-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:nsxt-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:firewall-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:genericdevice-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:mapper:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:jar:1.4.2:compile
|  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
|  |  \- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.2_jdk5:compile
|  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
|  +- com.van:denorm-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.van:hp-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.vmw.vapi:vapi-runtime:jar:2.7.0:compile
|  \- com.vmw.nsx.sdk:nsx-language-bindings:jar:2.0.0:compile
+- com.van:denorm-programs:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:test
|  \- com.van:impact:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:test
+- com.van:app:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  \- com.van:meta-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- com.van:resourcemanager:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- com.van:ui-model:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
|  \- org.unitils:unitils-core:jar:3.3:compile
|     \- ognl:ognl:jar:2.6.9:compile
+- com.van:query:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- com.van.grid:sdmgraph:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
|  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
|  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
|  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.3.1:compile
|  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13:compile
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
|  \- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
+- com.van:programs:jar:tests:0.001-SNAPSHOT:test
+- com.van:snmp:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.snmp4j:snmp4j:jar:2.4.3:compile
|  |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
|  \- org.snmp4j:snmp4j-agent:jar:2.4.2:compile
+- com.van:components:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
|  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:compile
|     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
+- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.77:compile
|  |  \- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.1:compile
|  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.77:compile
+- com.van:metrics-eval:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.20:compile
+- com.van:remote-control:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.0.1:compile
+- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-healthchecks:jar:3.0.1:compile
+- com.icegreen:greenmail:jar:1.5.5:test
+- com.van:support-request:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  \- com.van:storage-utils:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|     \- com.github.fge:json-patch:jar:1.9:compile
|        \- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.6:compile
|           \- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:compile
|              \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:compile
+- com.van:dns-request:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- com.van:service-health:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
+- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.4:compile
+- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
+- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
+- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.10.1:compile
+- com.van:syslog:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- com.van.external-clients:csp:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
|  \- com.auth0:java-jwt:jar:3.2.0:compile
+- com.van.external-clients:discovery:jar:0.001-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- dnsjava:dnsjava:jar:2.1.7:compile
+- com.univocity:univocity-parsers:jar:2.5.9:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:test
|  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
+- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.8:compile
|  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
+- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:0.9.1:compile
|  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:1.2:compile
+- com.google.guava:guava:jar:23.5-jre:compile
|  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
|  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.0.18:compile
|  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
|  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
+- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.3:provided
+- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.23.2:compile
|  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.23.2:compile
|  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
|  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.23.2:compile
|  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
|  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
|  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
|  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
|  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.5.0-b05:compile
+- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
+- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
+- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
+- org.apache.commons:commons-jexl:jar:2.1.1:compile
+- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
+- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
+- com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format:protobuf-java-format:jar:1.2:compile
+- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.1:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:jar:2.5.8:compile
|  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.2:compile
|  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.11:jar:0.7.0:compile
+- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
|  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
+- com.github.rholder:guava-retrying:jar:1.0.5:compile
+- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.8:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
\- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.5.2:test
```

Can someone let me know what is going wrong? How can I get around this error?

Comment: The only way that's possible is if you have mismatched versions of jetty-io and jetty-util classes.  Run [this code](https://gist.github.com/joakime/8106672) in your project (except: use `ManagedSelector.class` once and `QueuedThreadPool.class` once).  See where those classes are coming from. (should only be 1 location each, and with the same jetty version)

Comment: Thanks. Your code was helpful. jetty-io was 9.3.x and jetty-util was 9.4.x. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: FWIIW, running `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.eclipse.jetty` would give a smaller dependency tree so it is easier to spot the conflicting versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that's possible is if you have mismatched versions of `jetty-io` and `jetty-util` classes.

Run this code (in your project) to figure out where the classes are (it will report all locations, even if they are in multiple locations):

```java
public class WhereIsThisComingFrom
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        locate(ManagedSelector.class);
        locate(QueuedThreadPool.class);
    }

    public static void locate(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        try
        {
            ClassLoader cl = clazz.getClassLoader();
            String classAsResource = clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
            Enumeration<URL> urls = cl.getResources(classAsResource);
            System.out.printf("Looking for: %s%n", classAsResource);
            while (urls.hasMoreElements())
            {
                URL url = urls.nextElement();
                System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", url.toExternalForm());
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            System.out.printf("Whoops: cannot locate: %s%n", clazz);
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```